# API for leaving an iTunes review in-app

Tags: ios, api, ios4, itunes, review

Is there such an API for leaving an iTunes review in-app? Or is there something else I could use? What sort of solutions have you come up with?

Cheers guys, look forward to your ideas and experiences

Answer (score 1):

I use Appirater in many of my apps, which presents the user with a dialog on the X launch to ask if they'd like to leave a review, and that takes them to the App Store.  I've seen it (or similar) used in many apps.

The source for Appirater is here: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/

You can get your App ID before launch by looking in iTunes Connect, it's listed as the Apple ID under the app information.  It's a 9 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this inside of your app that I am aware of. In terms of reviewing from within my apps, I usually just have something like this:

```
- (IBAction) reviewPressed: (id) source {
   NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE"; 
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

You'll need to replace the ID in the URL with your own App ID.